# Analog clock from Windows in my application

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to use analog clock from Windows in my own application? Call it from some DLL for example.

Comment: You mean the clock control from Control Panel, Date and Time properties? Not the old clock accessory program?

Comment: Yes, i mean clock control from Control Panel, Date and Time properties.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a formally documented interface, i.e. it can break in future Windows versions. But for the current windows versions, it's certainly possible. Using the Shell, open the control panel, enumerate all items, find the clock item, and start it.

Comment: I think he meant steal the individual clock control to place in his application.